# P-Table In PrimeNG is triggering Multiple Call onRowSelection. I am making an API call on row selection and hence This is Impacting my performace

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using p-table along with checkboxes for rowSelection. On Selection Of every checkbox I need to Call API And fetch Data. Below is my code for Declaring table. On Check of row, event is triggered multiple Times, IdeallY it should trigger only On Check and uncheck of check box. Also I have To ensure That my row selection should happen on clicking anywhere in the row as well(using ). In below Code (selectionChange) event is Triggered multiple Times.

```js
<p-table #table [columns]="DemoArray" [value]="DemoData" [rows]="10" [lazy]="true"
            dataKey="ID" styleClass="styleClassName" class="styleClassName"
            [multiSortMeta]="[{field: 'origin', order: 1}]" (onLazyLoad)="lazyLoad($event)"
            [selection]="SelectedData" [totalRecords]="totalRecord"
            (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)" (selectAllChange)="onSelectAllChange($event)" 
            scrollHeight="380px" [scrollable]="true" 
            [virtualScroll]="true" [virtualRowHeight]="50">
```

Comment: Any Help from Primeng team will be appreciated,